# How to connect WIX template with 3rd party REST APIs?

Tags: node.js, html, velo

I created a simple web site using WIX platform. (https://www.wix.com/). I have some simple forms. Like customer registration and package management. All the UI part is done. And I have a Node.JS server to manage customers and packages. API is 100% done.

Now I need to connect WIX template with my NOde.JS REST API. Is there any possible ways to do this ?
My Node Server is deployed on a Ubuntu server and I can access it anywhere. 
Please help me on this.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, now Wix has this thing called `Wix Code` platform, which enables you to dynamically control your UI components and bind it to data coming from the outside.

To answer your question, they have this `fetch` API which you can use to write code to fetch your own server and get the data from it. Here is a link [Wix Code API - fetch](https://www.wix.com/code/reference/wix-fetch.html)

Anyway, this is their site, [Wix Code](https://www.wix.com/code/home), you may learn a lot more there. Also they have those tutorials and examples of many "how to..." and examples [Wix Code Tutorials and Videos](https://support.wix.com/en/wix-code/tutorials-examples-and-videos)

Cheers!